# Using subtype as type parameter in class

Tags: java, generics, covariance, contravariance

Consider the following code snippets

```
    public static <T> String typeName1(Class<T extends Object> c) {
        return c.getSimpleName();
    }
    public static  String typeName2(Class<? extends Object> c) {
        return c.getSimpleName();
    }
```

First one is showing a compile time error, while second one compiles successfully.
Why is it so?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the first one to this:

```
public static <T extends Object> String typeName(Class<T> c) {
    return c.getSimpleName();
}
```

and it will work. That's the difference in where you put the bounds. For type parameter, you declare bounds where you declare the type parameter, and not where you use it. While for wildcards, since there is no such declaration, you give bounds as and where you use it. BTW, `<T extends Object>` can just be `<T>`.

```
public static <T> String typeName(Class<T> c) {
    return c.getSimpleName();
}
```

Comment: But if we use in parameter level, arguments passed to the method will be restricted , whether the above one will do the same?

Comment: @harinewton The above methods can accept all those arguments that can be passed to `typeName2()` method with wildcard that you have.

Comment: Here I am using Object just for understanding

Comment: For example, consider I need to take classes that are sub classes of CharSequence, whether that validation can be done, if we just take class with type parameter T?

Comment: @harinewton No. For that you've to give bound - `<T extends CharSequence>`.

Comment: That is my question, why it is not allowed. Is there any reason?

Comment: @harinewton If you just use `<T>`, that means it can take any type. If you want to restrict the type to subtype of `CharSequence`, you have to give bounds - `<T extends CharSequence>` means, `T` can be something which extends `CharSequence`, so you won't be able to pass `Object.class`, where the method accepts `Class<T>` as parameter.